# SwiftUI - How to make/generate a subview via a function

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to be able to generate a subview every time a function is called, and have the new subview stacked on top of the previous ones so that every subview can still be interacted with separately. I have tried the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
        @State var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                EmptyView()
                    .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
                        addView(xVal: CGFloat.random(in:100...300))
                    })
            }
        }
    
        func addView(xVal: CGFloat) -> AnyView {
            return AnyView(interactiveView(val: xVal))
        }
    
    }

struct interactiveView: View {
    
    var val: CGFloat
    @State var tapped = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .foregroundColor(tapped ? .red : .green)
            .onTapGesture {
                tapped.toggle()
            }
            .position(x: val, y: 200)
    }
}
```

What I envisioned with the code above is that a new circle would pop up every second and can be interacted with separately from the other circles (i.e. tapping one circle does not affect the others). However, when I run the code, calling the addView function does not seem to generate any subviews (i.e. circles).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're not actually adding the result of `addView` to the view hierarchy at all. You'll want a way to add the view to a stored list (I used a `@State` variable) and then display those, most likely with `ForEach`.

Here's one solution:

```
struct ViewItem : Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var xVal: CGFloat
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var internalViews : [ViewItem] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(internalViews) { item in
                InteractiveView(val: item.xVal)
            }
        }.onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
            internalViews.append(ViewItem(xVal: CGFloat.random(in:100...300)))
        })
    }
}

struct InteractiveView: View {
    var val: CGFloat
    @State var tapped = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .foregroundColor(tapped ? .red : .green)
            .onTapGesture {
                tapped.toggle()
            }
            .position(x: val, y: 200)
    }
}
```